# How to detect if the given signal is Data or Clock signal type?

Tags: filter-design, signal-analysis, signal-detection

I have the edge information of the signal. I need to find if it's a Clock or Data type signal without iterating through all the points in edge vector...
Please provide your valuable inputs

Answer (score 1):

Clocks are very regular, i.e. all the up and down transitions are equally spaced. Data tends  to more irregular, i.e. spacing between transitions varies.

Comment: So I need to check all the points in the waveform to see if it's a train of equally spaced pulses or it's burst signal...???